# Why can't I remove the intermediate variable in my code?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, syntax, spread-syntax

I'm currently working with the spread syntax and ran into an unexpected issue.

The below snippet works (as expected), and doesn't throw any errors:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4] // create array of numbers

const copy = [...arr] // make a shallow copy of the array
copy.forEach(n => { // loop through array
  console.log(n + 1);
});
```

However, if I remove the intermediate variable `copy`, my code seems to throw an error:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4] // create array of numbers

[...arr].forEach(n => { // loop through array
  console.log(n + 1);
});
```

As you can see, the above code snippet throws an error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...

Whereas the first snippet does not. **Why is this happening?** To my understanding I should be able to replace `copy` with literal array it contains and have no issues (as I have done in the second snippet).

I expect the second snippet to behave as the first snippet, and not throw any errors.

**Note**: I'm aware that `[...arr]` seems redundant in this case, I've simply used this to demonstrate my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a semicolon and it works perfectly.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

[...arr].forEach(n => {
  console.log(n + 1);
});
```

The code was being evaluated without the newline - like this:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4][...arr]
```

Which resulted in your error.