# IIFE inside for loop error VM531:3 Uncaught TypeError: console.log(...)

Tags: javascript, function, loops, ecmascript-6

this code doesn't work

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  console.log("ddd")
  (function x() {
    console.log("eee")
  })();
}
```

VM531:3 Uncaught TypeError: console.log(...) is not a function
    at :3:3

these two works just fine

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  (function x() {
    console.log("eee")
  })()
  console.log("ddd")
}

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  (function x() {
    console.log("eee")
  })()
}
```

Comment: Add semi-colons to the end of your `console.log`'s and it will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have a semicolon after the `console.log` - otherwise it's trying to call the returned result of `console.log` (`undefined`) which isn't a function, which is calling your error.

Automatic semicolon insertion doesn't take into account whitespace.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  console.log("ddd");
  (function x() {
    console.log("eee")
  })();
}
```

Your code was trying to do:

```
console.log("ddd")(function x() {...})()
```

Which turns out to be:

```
undefined(function x() {...})()
```

Which results in your TypeError.

This problem of brackets overlapping due to a lack of semicolons is similar to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55841938/10221765) on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55841892/10221765).